# Creating an Oracle DB stored procedure for creating user accounts and/or checking if account already exists

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, registration

I am new to oracle db and especially stored procedures.

My main goal is to have a procedure that checks and makes  sure that an account (username or email) does not already exist before creating a user in my table.

The problem i have is:  When executing the procedure, nothing is inserted into the database.
If someone could check this code over and make sure it is correct, would help alot.

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE A2PROXYCREATEUSER (
        in_name IN VARCHAR2  
, in_password IN VARCHAR2  
, in_email IN VARCHAR2  
, in_subscript IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1 
, customaction IN VARCHAR2  
, userdata IN VARCHAR2  
, userdatalen IN NUMBER  
, returncode OUT NUMBER )
      AS
   CodeSuccess              constant number := 0;
   CodeAlreadyExists        constant number := 1;
   CodeInvalidUserName      constant number := 2;
   CodeAccountCreationDisabled      constant number := 3;
   CodeInvalidPassword      constant number := 4;
   CodeKeyInUser    constant number := 10;
   CodeInvalidKey       constant number := 11;
   current_name VARCHAR2(32);
   current_email varchar2(12);
   wonidseq number;
   BEGIN
   wonidseq := 0;
   returncode := CodeSuccess;

        SELECT NAME
        INTO   current_name
        FROM   WONUSER
        WHERE  NAME = in_name;
  returncode := CodeAlreadyExists;

        -- If the first SELECT statement above fails to return any
        -- records at all, then the NO_DATA_FOUND exception will be
        -- signalled. The following code reacts to this exception
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          BEGIN
           SELECT EMAIL
              INTO   current_email
              FROM   WONUSER
              WHERE  EMAIL = in_email;
        returncode:=CodeAlreadyExists;
EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          BEGIN
SELECT  UNIQUEID_SEQ.nextval into wonidseq from WONUSER;
              INSERT INTO WONUSER(WONUSERSEQ, NAME, PASSWORD, NEWPASSWORD, EMAIL, TRUSTLEVEL, COMMUNITYSEQ, ISBANNED, ISACTIVE)
                VALUES(wonidseq, in_name, in_password, NULL, in_email, 120, 0, 0, 1);
returncode := CodeSuccess;
        end;


          END;
    if returncode = CodeSuccess then
        commit;
    else
        rollback;
    end if;
      END;
```

EDIT:

I managed to fix the code (probably looks like a hack to someone who knows the syntax well)

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE A2PROXYCREATEUSER (
       in_name IN VARCHAR2  
, in_password IN VARCHAR2  
, in_email IN VARCHAR2  
, in_subscript IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1 
, customaction IN VARCHAR2  
, userdata IN VARCHAR2  
, userdatalen IN NUMBER  
, returncode OUT NUMBER )
      AS
   CodeSuccess              constant number := 0;
   CodeAlreadyExists        constant number := 1;
   CodeInvalidUserName      constant number := 2;
   CodeInvalidEmail     constant number := 7;

   CodeAccountCreationDisabled      constant number := 3;

   current_name VARCHAR2(32);
   current_email varchar2(12);
   wonidseq number;
   BEGIN

SELECT LoginName into current_name from WONUSER WHERE  loginname = in_name;
returncode := CodeAlreadyExists;
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            returncode := CodeSuccess;
 if returncode = CodeSuccess then
   BEGIN
 SELECT EMAIL into current_email from WONUSER where EMAIL = in_email;
 returncode := CodeAlreadyExists;
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            returncode := CodeSuccess;
              INSERT INTO WONUSER (WONUSERSEQ, LOGINNAME, PASSWORD, NEWPASSWORD, EMAIL, TRUSTLEVEL, COMMUNITYSEQ, ISBANNED, ISACTIVE,birthdate)
                VALUES(wonidseq, in_name, in_password, ' ', in_email, 120, 0, 0, 1, sysdate);
        commit;
    end;
else
rollback;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Well, did you step through it in a debugger, like SQLDeveloper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code would be this one:

```
PROCEDURE A2PROXYCREATEUSER (...)  AS

   CodeSuccess              constant number := 0;
   CodeAlreadyExists        constant number := 1;
   CodeInvalidUserName      constant number := 2;
   CodeInvalidEmail     constant number := 7;
   CodeAccountCreationDisabled      constant number := 3;


    CURSOR curWonUser IS
    SELECT *
    FROM WONUSER
    WHERE EMAIL = in_email OR NAME = in_name;
    WonUser curWonUser%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    OPEN curWonUser;
    FETCH curWonUser INTO WonUser;
    IF curWonUser%NOTFOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO WONUSER(WONUSERSEQ, NAME, PASSWORD, NEWPASSWORD, EMAIL, TRUSTLEVEL, COMMUNITYSEQ, ISBANNED, ISACTIVE)
            VALUES (UNIQUEID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, in_name, in_password, NULL, in_email, 120, 0, 0, 1);
        returncode = CodeSuccess;
        COMMIT;
    ELSE 
        returncode = CodeAlreadyExists;
    END IF;
    CLOSE curWonUser;

end;
```

Note, you are not using any of the other return codes.

Comment: That look's alot simpler than what i was doing!
I'm a little confused at what curser is?  I keep seeing it on the oracledb website but havnt found much of what it actually is

Comment: Have a look at this article, it gives you a good overview: [Oracle Magazine: Working with Cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)